# Paypal - warn website on payment

Tags: paypal

I'm building a SAAS based on a credits system, which are bought via Paypal.

Right now, I use the Payment Standard with PDT to check that the payment has been done correctly. When the transaction is done, Paypal redirects the client to a page on my website which checks that the transaction went well, and gives the amount of credits matching the price paid.

This works fine, but I have a problem : since the website need to be redirected from Paypal to add the credits, if the client is not redirected for whatever reason, the customer pays but receives no credit.

My question is thus : Is there any way to warn my website from Paypal in a more robust way, and is it possible to cancel a transaction in case of error, and How ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Paypal IPN so your server is notified when a payment completes. You can add additional fields to the payment so that you know things like the ID of a logged in user for example.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need ! I just miss one way to track the user when he buys the credit. Can I send some kind of token to paypal or something like that ?

Comment: You just need to add it as a field to the original 'button' which you can make hidden, and you'll get that information during checkout.

Comment: Nice and easy. In other words : perfect. Thanks for your help !